# Ontology of logogram, pictogram and ideogram

Tags: terminology, written-language

Is it fair to say that a pictograms are a subset of ideograms which are a subset of logograms?

What is an example of an ideogram that is not a logogram or pictogram?

Comment: Related question asked on the same day, five hours later: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/26918/difference-between-ideogram-and-logogram